# ReflectionException: Class config does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, phpunit, mockery

I am writing a test for the JobMapper and the response that I am getting is: 
`ReflectionException: Class config does not exist`. Although I have traced the issue, I don't seem to get anywhere near the solution.

An assumption of mine was that because in this line:

`$this->eloquentJobMapper->toEloquent($validJobModel)`

I am calling the DB, the current $app instance is not correctly initialized, therefore cannot hit the DB.

Any ideas on this one ?

```
use \Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase;
use MNF\MJ\Models\Job;
use MNF\MJ\Mapper\EloquentJobMapper;
use MNF\MJ\Repositories\EloquentJobRepository;
use \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade as Facade;
use \Illuminate\Container\Container as Container;
use MNF\MJ\Persistence\EloquentJob;
use \Illuminate\Foundation\Application;


class JobMapperTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * @var Job
     */
    protected $jobMock;

    /**
     * @var EloquentJobRepository
     */
    protected $eloquentJobRepositoryMock;

    /**
     * @var EloquentJobMapper $eloquentJobMapper
     */
    protected $eloquentJobMapper;

    /**
     * JobMapperTest setUp().
     */
    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->jobMock = Mockery::mock('MNF\MJ\Models\Job');
        $this->eloquentJobRepositoryMock = Mockery::mock('MNF\MJ\Repositories\EloquentJobRepository');
        $this->eloquentJobMapper = new EloquentJobMapper();

        $app = new Container();
        $app->singleton('app', 'Illuminate\Container\Container');
        $app->instance(Job::class, $this->jobMock);
        Facade::setFacadeApplication($app);

    }

    public function tearDown()
    {
        parent::tearDown();
        Mockery::close();
    }

    /**
     * Creates the application.
     *
     * @return Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface
     */
    public function createApplication()
    {
        return new Application();
    }

    //1) giving a valid a Job model,  I am getting back an Eloquent Job Model

    public function testGivingValidMJModelGettingBackEloquentMJModel()
    {
        $validJobModel = new Job();
        $validJobModel->setJobID(23)
          /// ..some setters

        $eloquentJob = $this->eloquentJobMapper->toEloquent($validJobModel);
        $this->assertInstanceOf(EloquentJob::class, $eloquentJob);

}
```

}

Comment: On Laravel 5, this error means that your class autoloads were not loaded. For anyone experiencing this now, they might want to look at their testing bootstrap code.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but I completely don't understand why you create new container object here:

```
$app = new Container();
$app->singleton('app', 'Illuminate\Container\Container');
$app->instance(Job::class, $this->jobMock);
Facade::setFacadeApplication($app);
```

this way probably you make container has no config class set. Instead of this probably you should use:

```
\App::instance(Job::class, $this->jobMock);
```

and it should be enough.

Comment: Thanks alot for your reply. Unfortunartely, I am getting the same error. Could this be related to the fact that it is a Laravel 4.2 installation ?

Comment: You haven't mentioned it's Laravel 4.2. It's really hard to say. It's possible that you use somewhere else config but you haven't showed the code